# Very slow, freeze and ask to log in for every apps

Tags: freeze, asus, zoom-meeting

I have an Asus AMDA RYZEN5 with Jammy Jellyfish UBUNTU. My computer is suddenly very slow for everything(opening an app, sending pictures or videos). Freezing on zoom always with impossibility to do anything with the mouse or on the keyboard(only forcing to close). Also, every app ask me to log in with name and password every time I reboot it.